# ESAPI-java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, spring-saml, esapi

Iam currently using esapi 2.2.0.0 version. When i tried to upgrade 2.2.0.0 to 2.5.2.0 iam getting this error..java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory LogFactory class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory) must be in class path.
I tried to add ESAPI.properties also but its not helped

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that I have previously answered this identical question  previously on SO, but to save us both the trouble of looking it up, instead just download the esapi-2.5.2.0-configuration.jar found under the 'Assets' section at https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/releases/tag/esapi-2.5.2.0. Unjar that jar file, find the **ESAPI.properties** file and replace that 2.5.2.0 version of **ESAPI.properties** one with the old one that you presumably kept from ESAPI 2.2.0.0. That ought to fix your problem. (If you are using the ESAPI `Encryptor`, you may also want to copy your **Encryptor.MasterKey** and **Encryptor.MasterSalt** properties from your 2.2.0.0 **ESAPI.properties** file. But unless you made configuration changes, that's probably all that you need to preserve.)

BTW, the reason you are getting that error is because the package namespace of `JavaLogFactory` changed when we started supporting SLF4J somewhere around 2.3.0.0. If you follow instructions in the release notes and read all the intervening release notes (well, at least through 2.3.0.0 or so), it probably would have been obvious.

Anyhow, HTH. -kevin

Comment: Hi kevin ,i have added ESAPI.Properties file still iam getting this error and in 2.2.0.0 we are not using any ESAPI.Properties file Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory

Comment: ESAPI pretty much will not work if it can't find any ESAPI.properties file at all. (But it looks a lot of places, including under $HOME/.esapi, etc.)  Anyway, you this 'ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory' in your ESAPI.properties fie. That is what you will find in the configuration jar that I referenced, so I think ESAPI is locating a DIFFERENT ESAPI.properties file  than you think it is.

Comment: i have addeed ESAPI.properties file at src/main/resources..in ESAPI.properties i have added 'ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory' but still iam encountering same issue and i cross checked only one file was there

Comment: @Mahesh - sorry; slow going through my email. Look up my email drop on the OWASP ESAPI wiki page and drop me an email and maybe we can sync up there or plan a Zoom meeting, etc. This forum doesn't lend itself well for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Some extension of the first answer.

ESAPI logger package structure was refactored in the 2.2.1.0 release.

To fix the issue you need to replace the old log factory class in your `ESAPI.properties` file with the correct one, e.g.:

```
#ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory
ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory
```

For more details, see [ESAPI 2.2.3.0 release notes](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/main/documentation/esapi4java-core-2.2.3.0-release-notes.txt)