# ESAPI 2.5.2 : Unable to locate resource esapi-java-logging.properties

Tags: esapi, classnotfound

I search everywhere but I am still stuck as everyone when trying to migrate (from 2.1.0) to 2.3.0.0+ version.
**Unable to locate resource esapi-java-logging.properties** (which is **just next to ESAPI.properties**)

This is caused by ESAPI JavaLogFactory behaviour that is not getting esapi-java-logging.properties (probably because of **interference*** with some other configuration in my application that only the developer of this esapi library could explain).

```
InputStream stream = JavaLogFactory.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("esapi-java-logging.properties")
```

[bug ESAPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmH3n.png)

**I assume that this is caused by some other configuration because when I create a simple project with {esapi 2.5.2.0 + javax.servlet-api 4.0.1} and with {ESAPI.properties + validation.properties + esapi-java-logging.properties} and it works perfectly.*

I have done what you have suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76225938/esapi-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-owasp-esapi-reference-javalogfactory/76914919#76914919) (I copy all content of ESAPI.properties of your link and I added only my own Encryptor.MasterKey and Encryptor.MasterSalt).
Please help!

Note1 : as it didn't work for 2.5.2.0, I also tried 2.3.0.0 but not better.

Note2 : the mandatory file esapi-java-logging.properties seems new because in 2.1 I can use JavaLoggingFactory (located in reference package) without it...

I also give the [link to GitHub](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/wiki/Configuration-Reference:-JavaLogFactory) (thanks avgvstvs even if I am still looking for the solution)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValidationException when upgrading esapi 2.2.0.0 to 2.3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76734781/validationexception-when-upgrading-esapi-2-2-0-0-to-2-3-0-0)

Comment: Thanks for the lin; unfortunately, everything seems correctly set : java.util.logging.config.class and java.util.logging.config.file are both null, what is the expected behaviour as in that cas, the library should read esapi-java-logging.properties.
+
I have created a simple maven project including only {esapi 2.5.2.0 + javax.servlet-api 4.0.1} and with {ESAPI.properties + validation.properties + esapi-java-logging.properties} and it works perfectly.

Comment: ***CONCLUSION*** my configuration for ESAPI is fine, only the developer of this library (@Kevin?) could know what could explain that in some environment, JavaLogFactory.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("esapi-java-logging.properties") cannot find anything.

Comment: I am still unable to migrate :-(

Comment: I would start a discussion at the github, but I can safely say that if you can't reproduce the problem with some sort of minimal configuration that Kevin or myself could pull down and troubleshoot, it will be hard to offer much more help than what's already out there.

Comment: Any idea since the discussion? I really need help from the developer because I can't guess what cause this issue inside the library

Comment: You haven't provided us with a test project that reproduces the issue.  Like I said in august, we can't offer you much help if we can't reproduce.

Comment: I have added a screenshot (cf link in my post) but I am sure you can understand I can't give you the code of my application and if I build a simple test project I don't have the issue

Comment: I think you're warring with Eclipse.  First, when you run a build of your application using maven on the command line, does your resource file get packaged in with the other resources?  If yes, then check if your eclipse profile is configured to use the same JDK as command line.  Also try Deleting your eclipse settings files out of your repo '.classpath' and '.settings/` are culprits but not the only ones) and then re-import the project as a maven project.  You might have to fully re-clone (from the command line)  If you reclone you'll have to re-delete eclipse files.

Comment: More than anything,, make sure it works from the command line first, and then you'll have to figure out how to make eclipse happy from there.

Comment: Also, if this failure is happening via unit tests, don't forget to put the same logging file in src/test/resources or else you'll run into a similar problem.  JUnit won't pick up files you put src/main although if it's packaged into a binary that ought to work.